# Tableview for presenting nested JSON programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a JSON tree that represent address. Something like this,

```
- Address Tree
    - Address Tree Deeper
    - Address Tree Deeper
    - Address Tree Deeper
        - Address Tree More Deeper
        - Address Tree More Deeper
        - Address Tree More Deeper
        - Address Tree More Deeper
            - Address Tree Deepest
            - Address Tree Deepest
            - Address Tree Deepest
            - Address Tree Deepest
- Address Tree
    - Address Tree Deeper
    - Address Tree Deeper
    - Address Tree Deeper
        - Address Tree More Deeper
        - Address Tree More Deeper
        - Address Tree More Deeper
        - Address Tree More Deeper
            - Address Tree Deepest
            - Address Tree Deepest
            - Address Tree Deepest
            - Address Tree Deepest
```

I want to display that tree using table and user could select its child, but I don't know how to represent that. I mean, should we create multiple `ViewController` (and ofcourse its scene in storyboard) then we push every we go deeper into address child? Or maybe I could create `UITableView` programmatically?

Or there are any approach that I can use for that case? I think about reusing viewcontroller but I don't have any clue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: do you know how many possible sub categories are there?

Comment: I think there are 3 level sub categories @jo3birdtalk

Comment: you've just answered your question. just create 3 UITableViewControllers (since it is the maximum) inside your IB, and push the view controllers accordingly if that dictionary has sub categories in it.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think there are any better way to create something like that out there, I am doubting my self with that approach :D Thank you so much, @jo3birdtalk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 3 UITableViewControlle‌​rs (since it is the maximum) inside your IB, and push the view controllers accordingly if that dictionary has sub categories in it.

An example how you should do it:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if(yourDictionary[indexPath.row].yourVariable != nil){
        let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextViewController") as! ScoutPage
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```